# Hibernate - Spring Boot - save object with foreign key to the other table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use Hibernate and Spring Boot and I have the following problem:
I want to save my object of type Framework in PostgreSQL:

```
public class Framework extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sorting_type_id", unique = true)
    private FrameworkSortingType frameworkSortingType;
```

My `FrameworkSortingType` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "framework_sorting_type")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FrameworkSortingType extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "environmental_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SortingType environmental;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "social_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SortingType social;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "governance_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SortingType governance;
}
```

And `SortingType` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "sorting_type")
public class SortingType extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
}
```

And I'm doing the following test - in `Postman` I want to save such an object (frameworkSortingType object without IDs):

```
{
"id": 335799,
"frameworkSortingType": {
    "environmental":{
        "type": "alphabetically"
    },
     "social":{
        "type": "numerically"
    },
     "governance":{
        "type": "alphabetically"
    }
}
}
```

My SortingType table has only 2 constant rows:

```
id type
1  alphabetically
2  numerically
```

And I want to store in my `FrameworkSortingType` table only the foreign key ID to the `SortingType` table but currently there are stored in my `FrameworkSortingType` completely new IDs to the `SortingType` table in which there are ADDED new rows with new values (and `SortingType` table should not be modified because should work like an ENUM but -> has been changed by adding new rows):
**SortingType** table:
[image]

and in my `FrameworkSortingType` table there are saved completely new IDs to the `SortingType` rows instead of foreign key IDS like 1 or 2 (instead of 751801 should be 1 as PK in `SortingType`, instead of 751803 should be 2 as PK from `SortingType` etc.):
[image]

Where is the problem? Where I made mistake?
Maybe should I change data that are sent from the frontend? And of course I'd like to send to the backend value like "alphabetically" instead of ID because the ID can be different on each database.

**EDIT**

Everything works as expected when I remove cascade=CascadeType.ALL from FrameworkSortingType entity but I would prefer to send only value from the frontend without ID of SortingType table (that works like an enum in DB in my case)

Comment: [alphabetically, numerically] are enums from master table i.e SortingType this is to be generated only once at the time of booting or manual entry, you should avoid any update or insert operation on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid updating master(also called as main reference) table from any kind of interaction and you can update it only offline or through some admin interfaces. Also, a refresher wherever you use  `JoinColumn` that entity becomes the owning side of the entity. Hence any operation from that entity will be applicable to association annotation like OneToOne in this case. So please use Cascade.ALL carefully.

Here are some changes i have done to entity and how i have implemented.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "sorting_type")
public class SortingType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private SortingTypeName name;


    public enum SortingTypeName {
        ALPHABETICAL,
        NUMERICALLY
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public SortingTypeName getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(SortingTypeName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static SortingType newAlphabetSortingType() {
        SortingType sortingType = new SortingType();
        sortingType.name = SortingTypeName.ALPHABETICAL;
        return sortingType;
    }

    public static SortingType newNumericSortingType() {
        SortingType sortingType = new SortingType();
        sortingType.name = SortingTypeName.NUMERICALLY;
        return sortingType;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "framework_sorting_type")
public class FrameworkSortingType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "environmental_id")
    private SortingType environmental;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "social_id")
    private SortingType social;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "governance_id")
    private SortingType governance;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public SortingType getEnvironmental() {
        return environmental;
    }

    public void setEnvironmental(SortingType environmental) {
        this.environmental = environmental;
    }

    public SortingType getSocial() {
        return social;
    }

    public void setSocial(SortingType social) {
        this.social = social;
    }

    public SortingType getGovernance() {
        return governance;
    }

    public void setGovernance(SortingType governance) {
        this.governance = governance;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "framework")
public class Framework {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "framework_id")
    private FrameworkSortingType frameworkSortingType;


    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public FrameworkSortingType getFrameworkSortingType() {
        return frameworkSortingType;
    }

    public void setFrameworkSortingType(FrameworkSortingType frameworkSortingType) {
        this.frameworkSortingType = frameworkSortingType;
    }
}
```

Unit Test to prove the concept

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
class MasterTableExample {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Rollback(false)
    @Test
    void testSortingTypeSave() {
        SortingType alphabetType = SortingType.newAlphabetSortingType();
        SortingType numericType = SortingType.newNumericSortingType();

        entityManager.persist(alphabetType);
        entityManager.persist(numericType);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(alphabetType.getId());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(numericType.getId());

        // Prepare FrameworkSortingType object
        FrameworkSortingType frameworkSortingType = new FrameworkSortingType();
        frameworkSortingType.setEnvironmental(searchSortingType(SortingType.SortingTypeName.ALPHABETICAL));
        frameworkSortingType.setSocial(searchSortingType(SortingType.SortingTypeName.NUMERICALLY));
        frameworkSortingType.setGovernance(searchSortingType(SortingType.SortingTypeName.NUMERICALLY));

        // Prepare Framework object
        Framework framework = new Framework();
        framework.setFrameworkSortingType(frameworkSortingType);
        entityManager.persist(framework);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(frameworkSortingType.getId());
        Assertions.assertNotNull(framework.getId());
    }

    private SortingType searchSortingType(SortingType.SortingTypeName name) {
        return (SortingType) entityManager.createQuery("select st from SortingType st where st.name='" + name + "'").getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

I have used `Rollback(false)` just in case you wish to see the changes still present in db after test execution.

We are storing the Enum entity before. When a Framework is created with FrameworkStoringType both the data is persisted irrespective of `SoringType` table getting updated.
Try adding `entityManager.remove(framework);` end of the statement you would see `framework` along with `frameworkstoringtype` deleted from database and nothing happens to SortingType persisted rows. You can see i have not used `entity.persist(frameworkSortingType)` the association does it for me.

Please note that i have removed `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` from `FrameworkSortingType` as this is what might cause extra addition and deletion from `SortingType` table.